# Effect on Eigenvalues by exchanging columns

Tags: linear-algebra

I have  a short questions. Can there be made a general statement about what is happening to the Eigenvalues of a Matrix if I exchange two columns ?

Comment: Well the *product* of the eigenvalues changes sign.  I don't think (but would be delighted if I am wrong) that you can say any more than that, though.  Here are some test examples: $(1)$ $\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 6}$ has eigenvalues $1$ and $6$ .  After a column swap it has eigenvalues $\sqrt{6}$ and $-\sqrt{6}$.  $(2)$ $\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 4}$ has eigenvalues $1$, $-2$, and $4$, while the matrix with swapped first and third columns has eigenvalues of $-2$ (with algebraic multiplicity $2$) and $2$ (so there aren't even the same number of distinct eigenvalues in this case).

Comment: If your matrix is symmetric, then [this result applies](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/106191/eigenvalues-of-product-of-two-symmetric-matrices).  That's about the nicest that the general statement is going to get.

Comment: See also problem III.6.4 from the latest edition of Bhatia.

Answer (score 0):

When you exchange two columns of a matrix, the determinant of the matrix is multiplied by -1. However, the eigenvalues of a matrix are the roots of the characteristic polynomial, which is defined in terms of the determinant of the matrix minus a variable.
Therefore, exchanging two columns of a matrix does not change the eigenvalues of the matrix. This is because the eigenvalues are solutions to the equation det(A−λI)=0
where A is your matrix, I is the identity matrix, and λ is a scalar. The determinant of the matrix A changes sign when two columns are swapped, but this does not affect the solutions λ to the equation above
However, it’s important to note that while the eigenvalues remain the same, the corresponding eigenvectors will generally be different. This is because eigenvectors are dependent on the specific arrangement of values in the matrix. So, while the eigenvalues give us information about the overall ‘shape’ of the transformation represented by the matrix, the eigenvectors tell us about the ‘direction’ of this transformation, which does change when columns are swapped.